# how to replace url parameter c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http

```
https://www.stote.it/bais/%ID%
```

I have a URL like the above and a method that takes key. I want to replace ID with key and make a get request. I can make the get request if I manually replace ID with a value, but I want to do it in code. Any help?

```
private String getEmailTemplate(string key)
{
    string html = string.Empty;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return html;
```

Comment: `url = url.Replace("%ID%", key);`?

Comment: will give it a try and get back thanks anyway for the prompt response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `url` is arbitrary, make it `https://www.stote.it/bais/{0}` and use `String.Format(url, key)`.

This way if you ever add more arguments, there is no complicated string replacement.